# urllib3 and curl not works with some sites but browser works

Tags: python, curl, networking, python-requests, urllib

I am having an issue with curl and urllib on python3 that I dont know how to solve.
whenever I try to send a request to some specific files , I dont get any response and the script waits basically forever. but , when I open the same site from browser it works.(see site example below).

this is my code :

```
import urllib.request
       hdr = { 'User-Agent' : 'super happy flair bot by /u/spladug' }
       req = urllib.request.Request(url,headers=hdr)
       data = urllib.request.urlopen(req,timeout=10).read()
       return data
```

Stuff I tried:

1. Changing user agent
2. Adding and removing timeouts
3. curl these sites(it's just keep waiting for ever
   but still there are some sites(that ends with image file extension like http://xxx.xxx/aaa.png or .jpg) that I just can't get a response, and if I am setting a timeout I am getting TimeOutError. but if i open the same site in the chrome everything working fine. Does someone have any solution or faced the issue?

site example - https://sgfm.elcorteingles.es/SGFM/dctm/MEDIA03/202006/24/00117731276964____5__210x210.jpg

Comment: You said you tried changing user agent. Have you used real user agent value (from an actual browser)?

Comment: @Aziz yes, i tried a real user agent and still have not got any response back

Comment: I have tried `curl` and `requests` on that URL, and both timeout. I think the server detects when the request is not from an actual browser, but it is not clear how it does that. I have tried to mimic headers from Firefox and Chrome, but it still didn't work. I am not sure if it black-lists the client IP at some point.